# How to get gridview with variable sized gridview items?

Tags: gridview, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to show images in grouped gridview. Now all the images will have various height & width So I want to show images in it's original height width. I tried `WrapGrid`, `VariableSizedWrapGrid` & `VirtualizingStackPanel` but didn't get the output. Please note my model class contains image name (path), height & width. So how can I show images like given below ?

[image]

Comment: Okay, I added all the code to my answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I doubt you tried a WrapPanel. There's not one in WinRT.

Using VariableSizedWrapGrid you get a result something like this:

[image]

Using a WrapGrid you get a result something like this:

[image]

Presto! The trick?

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        var _Random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        var _Colors = typeof(Windows.UI.Colors)
            // using System.Reflection;
            .GetRuntimeProperties()
            .Select((c, i) => new
            {
                Title = c.Name,
                Color = (Windows.UI.Color)c.GetValue(null),
                ColSpan = _Random.Next(20, 300),
                RowSpan = _Random.Next(20, 300),
            });
        this.Groups = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<object>();
        this.Groups.Add(new { Title = "Mostly Red", Children = _Colors.Where(x => x.Color.R > 200) });
        this.Groups.Add(new { Title = "Mostly Green", Children = _Colors.Where(x => x.Color.G > 200) });
        this.Groups.Add(new { Title = "Mostly Blue", Children = _Colors.Where(x => x.Color.B > 200) });
    }
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<object> Groups { get; private set; }
}

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel />
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource 
            x:Name="MyCsv"
            IsSourceGrouped="True"
            ItemsPath="Children"
            Source="{Binding Groups}"
            d:Source="{Binding Groups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=local:MyViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCsv}}">
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Rectangle Height="20" Width="20" Fill="{Binding Brush}" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                            <TextBlock FontSize="40" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <local:WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="2000" />
                        <!--<VariableSizedWrapGrid Margin="0,0,80,0" ItemHeight="1" ItemWidth="1" />-->
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,80,0" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="{Binding RowSpan}" Width="{Binding ColSpan}">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}" />
                    </Grid.Background>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>

</Grid>
```

But there's one gotcha. I am not correctly setting the width of the WrapPanel. In the code above, I've defaulted it to 2000 (which is ridiculous). You'll have to figure that part out and post your solution here. (I can't do *everything*) Otherwise, it's what you are asking for 100%.

The WinRT WrapPanel is on my blog http://jerrynixon.com (on the left column)

Good luck, Farhan.

See also: [ms forum where you asked the same thing](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/76fcebbd-53f5-4433-b415-1f3b64cc2e1c)

Comment: Hi, I have posted my code in question (UPDATE 2), it is not working, it's just showing blank screen.

Comment: Excellent, finally it worked. My mistake was in `CollectionViewSource` binding rest was all correct. Now I have to think how to decide width of `WrapPanel`. I would be glad to have suggestion from your, Jerry.

Comment: +1 for a nice solution.  You can resolve the `WrapPanel`'s `Width` issue by using a proper [`WrapPanel` implementation](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/WrapPanel/WrapPanel.cs).

Comment: This was a hell of a job to figure out without a fixed height or width. In the end I made the width into a bindable value (that was fixed to the window size in my case) and calculated the height by adding the largest number value each time a row was done. Then I set the Height property of the CustomWrapPanel. To prevent unnecessary Height updates I made a check to only update the Height Propery when it was actually different. I hope this helps someone at some point at some time :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this is the layout you want then you don't want a **Grid** View for the layout since it is not a grid. A `GridView` will size all its items based on the first item's size. You would most likely need a custom `ItemsControl` implementation for that layout.

Comment: Yeah, will still need a `WrapPanel` though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have options to use html/winjs for the application, you can try out [list view item template sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-item-templates-7d74826f) scenario 4 - "Creating a templating function that can span multiple cells". Here you may opt for using smaller grid unit, and define multiple css classes. In the item template fn based on image size, use the best fit css class to scale the image.

for example:

```
.square-image
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

// 4:3 aspect ratio
.landscape-image
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}

// aspect ratio 4:6
portrait-image
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

you get the idea. more css classes with different aspect ratios can be defined. In this case, you need to use `-ms-grid-row-align: center` for one dimension and other dimension as `100%` for the item to ensure image fits the cell and does not get distorted.

If you can not use winjs, then I see some samples which talk about variable grid size in GridView for c#. but I have not tried them out. These links might be helpful.

- [Variable size grouped gridview](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/966aa897-1413-46f0-bef7-663de36f9423)
- [Grid with variable size items](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/GridView-with-variable-b2346047)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's XAML/C# project, not HTML/WinJS

Comment: for xaml, you can try the links in the answer in case they help.

Comment: All the examples are based on row span & col span I want to set height & width.