# ItemsControl, on binding text cuts down from end

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

Iam working on a win 8.1app. I have a datatemplate

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="RadioOptionDataTemplate">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0 0 0 15">
                <Run Text="{Binding name}"/><Run Text=":"/>
            </TextBlock>
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding GetOptions}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RadioButton Content="{Binding}" Margin="0 0 10 10" IsChecked="True"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

It show data like this

[image]

Now if you see text cuts down from right end. If I set static content of radio button than everything looks well.

I want to know why this is happening in case of binding.

Answer (score 0):

ItemsControl Item's Widths are calculating based on how much the size has it's first item needs. In your code 'No Rice' is your first item text & the second and third item texts are longer than the first item text. That is because the text wraps.

And if you set the first item text is longer , all other items will fit in the view & text will  not cut off.

You can use text wrapping as one method for avoiding text cut off. Or you have to create a  Items control with variable item widths.

Please check the following link for creating grid view with variable item width

[How to Display Gridview items with variable width in Window 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084213/how-to-display-gridview-items-with-variable-width-in-window-8)

Thanks