# Grouped GridViewItems of varying heights and that wrap

Tags: gridview, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

My Windows Store app has a `GridView` that must contain grouped `GridViewItem`s which are of the same width but can be any arbitrary height depending on their content.  Within each group, the items should flow from top to bottom then, when the available height is used up, wrap to the next column.  The whole `GridView` is within a `Grid` row that has a star (*) height, which I think gives it a fixed vertical space.  So I don't understand why I'm having so much trouble making items wrap and thus flow into the next column.

I have been trying out various panels in the `ItemsPanelTemplate` of `GridView.ItemsPanel` and `GroupStyle.Panel`, but I have been unable to achieve the desired layout.

Unless I misunderstand the usage of `VariableSizedWrapGrid`, using it in both `Panel` properties seems like what I need.  Although it gives me the correct wrapping, it does not allow for variations in height.  That is, every item's height is set to that of the first item.

The problem I am having with `ItemsWrapGrid` is that it's applying the height of the first cell to every cell.

I tried using `VariableSizedWrapGrid` with its `Orientation` property set to `Horizontal` for just the `GridView.ItemsPanel` property (leaving `GroupStyle.Panel` to its default).  This allows me the varying item heights I need.  But then the items do not flow into the next column within each group.  Setting the `MaximumRowsOrColumns` property had no effect, but even if it did that's not what I want since the wrapping should depend on a particular screen's height - not on an arbitrary number set in XAML.

I've tried many variations without success.  This is what the XAML looks like now.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="subItems" Source="{Binding SubItems}" IsSourceGrouped="True" ItemsPath="SubItems"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="My Subheader" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0,0,7,3"/>
    <GridView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource subItems}}" SelectionMode="None" Margin="0,3"
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelector}">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="294"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

How can I achieve grouped cells with variable height but that wrap within each group?

Comment: Can you post the XAML for your GridView and the grid that contains it?

Comment: @ChrisLava: Okay, I posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16843050) with an accepted answer that recommends using a ported WrapPanel.  The WrapPanel used there has an issue with its Width, but I also found [a proper WrapPanel implementation](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/WrapPanel/WrapPanel.cs) that works.