# represent data set in HubSection: Different styles for GridViewItems or access to GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

I want to represent objects in `HubSection`, but they don't have to be presented in the same way. I have also two additional buttons: `Add new session` and `Show all`.

[image]

I wanted to use `GridView`, but I don't know how to use different styles depending of some the object's properties.

The second option is just create `Grid` and access to it from code according to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx).

Which option is recommended in this case, if first, how can I use different styles in `GridView` in Windows8.1 application?

Comment: ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector is your friend when you want to achieve different appearence for items based on their properties

Comment: @verdesrobert `ItemTemplateSelector` seems promising, I will check it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector is your friend when you want to achieve different appearance for items based on their properties

Example here http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-8---winrt-datatemplateselector-change-the-color-of-listboxitem-depending-on-condition

Comment: Smalls tests've runed ok. I will check it on my project and will response you. Thank you.

Comment: Is there posibility to use idfferent tile's height in `GridView` or should I use three `ListView` insted, because in `GridView` height and width are setted like in first element, but in `ListView` only height is setted?

Comment: If you put a `GridViewItem` in the `DataTemplate` you can set the size to whatever you want

Comment: To achieve that there are some options here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843050/how-to-get-gridview-with-variable-sized-gridview-items